# Why it's impossible to do in-object collision detection?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

Is there a particular reason why Apple would choose to only allow collision detection through the world, rather than allowing individual objects to detect when they collide with other things? This seems like a horrible design choice, but since I haven't found much complaining I'm guessing there is something I'm missing. So, is there?

Comment: The only thing that cross my mind is that the collision algorithm is left to the developer to come up with it.

Comment: Mozilla has an article about 2D collisions. I am not sure if it can help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: The thing is that they actually do collision detection, but it's impossible to do it in-object (meaning to have something like `object.onCollision`). Rather, the only way to  detect collision is in the `scene`, through a `PhysicsContactDelegate`, which means that all collisions must be detected through the `PhysicsWorld` as generic collisions between two generic nodes, that must then be handled on a case by case basis, which seems horrible from a code design perspective, as you end up with a giant collision detection function with a bunch of checks to see what kind of collision is happening.

Comment: @AugustoQ The collision & contact detection is Ok once you’ve used it. You define which objects collide with (i.e. bounce off) each other and the engine handles all that. You also define which contacts you are interested in and when a contact occurs you `didBegin` function is called and is passed the 2 objects that have contacted and the exact point(s) at which the contact occurred. The function generally does get too large. You can then use object- or class-specific functions to handle the contact.

Comment: @SteveIves It is possible to do object specific functions? I haven't found any mention of this in the docs or anywhere. If it is then it is exactly what I need and would completely null this question :D

Comment: @AugustoQ Sort of. Once you’ve worked out that (for  example) your `player` node has collided with a `missile` node, you could call `player.hitBy(missile)` if you could elaborate your exact requirements we could maybe help more. Remember that pretty much every 2D game out there works with the collision and contact detection SK provides.

Comment: Although your `didBegin` function will have a series of tests (usually a ‘switch’ construct) to see which 2 objects have made contact, it never gets huge and un-manageable as you can code the specific contact code in other functions or within your sprite subclasses if you are using them.

Comment: Because on object detection is a terrible design principle and highly inefficient.  You need to get through your entire update in 1/60th of a second,  messaging individual objects to get this done would kill your performance.

Comment: How do you determine who hit who in an object to object collision?   Also, how do you handle the calls?  Both A and B will get the message a contact happed, what is your priority?  In the scenario If B hits A, A dies, if A hits B, B dies,  how can you handle this at the object level?   Also, what happens when B dies before the physics calls on B?  You either still have to retain B, or do extra steps to check for existence.  Lot of problems that gets easily solved when you have a separate delegate to handle both scenarios. Think of it like a referee.

Comment: @SteveIves sorry for the delay. What I wanted to do was to make the detection itself on the player, instead of having to do all the collision detections centrally and then delegate the collisions accordingly. This would make the project more organized, as it makes explicit what contacts should be handled by what. As far as I know, this is the norm for other game engines and such.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon this sort of makes sense. But in the end, having on-object detection can be done through a central referee (in fact, I cannot see how it would be done otherwise) as you say, but still allow for the superior abstraction of on-object detection, which allows for better code organization, which is something that should be strived for by a framework such as SceneKit.

Comment: ... the central referee IS the delegate, but the delegate needs to know the rules to the game. There is no way a framework can know the rules to a particular game.

Comment: We have extensions,  you can easily extend SKSpriteNode to be able to handle your object collision code if you are worried about code organization. (technically you would extend PKPhysicsBody, but you do not have access to that object [SKPhysicsBody is a wrapper class I wouldn’t recommend extending that])

Comment: Btw, PhysicsKit is based on Box2D if you are curious about how things are done and why they are done the way they are.

Comment: @AugustoQ The contact detection is quite efficient. From what I've seen it appear as though every time the SK engine draws a frame and has to draw 2 physics bodies in a way that indicates they have contacted, it does a simple Boolean AND of the relevant bit masks and if the result isn't 0, it takes poiinters to the 2 physics bodies involved and the co-ordinates of the contact and adds it to a queue for the `didBegin` function of the delegate to handle.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon what I meant is that you should be able to define on-object collision detection (as in Physics Body components having a function onCollision or something like that). As Steve suggested, it could be done through a world delegate that then delegates the contacts as it recognizes them. However, what I'm asking is if it wouldn't make sense for the framework itself do this rather than leaving it for the programmer, as it forces you to either implement this or go with a out-of-object solution, which kind of breaks the architecture of the program.

Comment: Defining it adds complexity.  As far as SpriteKit is concerned, you are not supposed to work at the object level.  You are not generally suppose to subclass SKSpriteNode node, so having it at the object level does not make sense.  You would have to assign a delegate block to your physics body, on top of making the referee delegate.  If you were designing this efficiently from an architecture stand point, you would be using GamePlayKit so that you can use the ECS design.  You would then be using components to handle the problems you are facing, thus no need for in object collision delegate.

Comment: I'm using GameplayKit, though, and I need to detect when an object touches another, so the first object can do something. How would that be done through GameplayKit? When I search for collision detection it always takes me to SceneKit/SpriteKit

Answer (score 0):

Some great comments here and not sure why either.  They base the whole thing on nodes and names of nodes - seems like it could be better as looking things up after the fact is slower.  Here is how I handled it, similar to what others are saying.

Since I have a bunch of missiles, I just name the node = "Missi" + String(format: "%04d", vIndex), name = "Explo" + String(format: "%04d", vIndex), etc., that way I can prefix what I'm looking for and go directly to my array of nodes and do my thing.  I have hundreds of things going, but the collision function is pretty small.

```
func physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact)
    {
        guard let nodeNameA = contact.nodeA.name else { return }
        guard let nodeNameB = contact.nodeB.name else { return }

        //print("CONTACT: \(nodeNameA) \(nodeNameB)")
        if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Explo" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Enemy")
        {
            gameControl.defenseMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameB.suffix(4))!)
        }
        if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Enemy" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Explo")
        {
            gameControl.defenseMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameA.suffix(4))!)
        }

        if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Explo" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Missi")
        {
            //print("HIT")
            gameControl.enemyMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameB.suffix(4))!)
        }
        if(nodeNameA.prefix(5) == "Missi" && nodeNameB.prefix(5) == "Explo")
        {
            //print("HIT")
            gameControl.enemyMissileHit(vIndex: Int(nodeNameA.suffix(4))!)
        }
    }
```

I don't subclass nodes, I create classes such as DefenseObject with the stuff I want, then create an array that I can directly access or loop through.

```
var defenseObjects:                     [Int:DefenseObject] = [:]    

class DefenseObject: ObjectBase
{
    var index: Int = 0                              // Index of object
    var name: String = ""                           // Object name
    var isActive: Bool = false                      // Object is active
    init(vGameType: gameTypes, vCount: Int, position: SCNVector3)
    {
        super.init(vGameType: vGameType, vIndex: vCount)
        isActive = true
        name = "Enemy" + String(format: "%04d", vIndex)
    }
}
```

Then I can go right to the index and do defenseObjects[NDex].call().  I also don't try to cleanup the nodes during a wave, I set an isActive switch and hide them.  At the end of the wave, I clean 'em up.

Hope that helps.